# Weird function inside forEach in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, foreach

I have found the following code in a JSP

```
<c:forEach var="user" items="${page.content}">
    ${f:h(user.id)}
</c:forEach>
```

What does the `f:h` do?

### Edit

`f` is mapped to an uri that didn't exist

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://amateras.sf.jp/functions" prefix="f"%>
```

Comment: At the top of the JSP file, `f` is mapped to a tag library, same as `c` is mapped to `http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core` using an entry like `<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>`. What is `f` mapped to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`http://amateras.sf.jp/functions` is a URI used by the Project Amateras
tag library.
The [documentation](http://amateras.osdn.jp/cgi-bin/fswiki_en/wiki.cgi?page=JSEL) says about `f:h`:

> `f:h(String value)` Escape HTML tags